# SIFT- image comparison

Tags: sift

I am comparing two images using SIFT in java using sift implementation by Stephan Saalfeld-- http://fly.mpi-cbg.de/~saalfeld/Projects/javasift.html. But due to lack of proper example,i am finding difficult in using it. I am able to get the descriptors for the two images, then their corresponding matching descriptors and finally applying RANSAC to neglect the false matches. Now, i am left with a number of inliers. But I am confused how to conclude if two images are similar or not?

Answer (score 0):

RANSAC gives you the transformation matrix (including translation,rotation, and scaling values). Using this information you can try to fit images on each other in order to see the matches that are found by SIFT.

An advantage of RANSAC is its ability to do robust estimation of the model parameters, i.e., it can estimate the parameters with a high degree of accuracy even when a significant number of outliers are present in the data set. A disadvantage of RANSAC is that there is no upper bound on the time it takes to compute these parameters. When the number of iterations computed is limited the solution obtained may not be optimal, and it may not even be one that fits the data in a good way. In this way RANSAC offers a trade-off; by computing a greater number of iterations the probability of a reasonable model being produced is increased. Another disadvantage of RANSAC is that it requires the setting of problem-specific thresholds.
RANSAC can only estimate one model for a particular data set. As for any one-model approach when two (or more) model instances exist, RANSAC may fail to find either one. The Hough transform is an alternative robust estimation technique that may be useful when more than one model instance is present.

Concluding, you can say how much two images are similar. It cannot always tell you that it is a total match or a total difference. So you will get the matches after applying RANSAC. Then you can find out that the percentage of the good matches over total matches, and then you need to decide according to this information.